# C# Ajax.BeginForm FormValidation Dual Post Issue

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax.beginform, formvalidation.io

When using the `formvalidation.io` libraries with `Ajax.BeginForm` the `[HttpPost]` method is called twice.

I can confirm that I am not referencing `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` more than once as that is a common mistake, nor am I using wildcards to reference `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` in my BundleConfig which I believe can also introduce the same issue.

I am also using `PartialViewResult` and not `ActionResult` to ensure I am not re-including `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` via the `_Layout.cshtml`

From extensive testing, trying to eliminate the issue I have found that removing code that initialises formvalidation removes the dual post issue. The reason for this, is that formvalidation when initialised adds `novalidate="novalidate"` to the form.

I'd like to however retain the formvalidation functionality to prevent the form from being posted without correct data being entered, but also prevent the unnecessary extra HttpPost call.

Please see my code below, to demonstrate the issue:

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
routeCollection.MapRoute("Test", "Home/Test/{id}/{form}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Test", id = UrlParameter.Optional, form = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
bundleCollection.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scriptBundle/_test").Include("~/Scripts/_test.js"));
```

**Test.cs**

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public PartialViewResult Test(int id, bool form)
{
    var test = new WebApplication1.Models.Test
    {
        Id = id,
        Description = "Blah"
    };

    return PartialView(!form ? "_Test" : "_TestForm", test);
}

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Test(WebApplication1.Models.Test model)
{
    return PartialView(!ModelState.IsValid ? "_TestForm" : "_Test", model);
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Test</div>
            <div class="panel-body" id="TestBody">
                <table class="table table-bordered no-margin-bottom">
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Model.Id</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Model.Description</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">@Ajax.ActionLink("Edit Test", "Test", "Home", new { id = Model.Id, form = true }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "TestBody" }, new { title = "Click to Edit Test" })</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**_TestForm.cshtml**

```
@using WebApplication1.Helpers
@model WebApplication1.Models.Test
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Test", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "TestBody" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal", Id = "TestForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    <fieldset>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Description</span>
                @Html.TextBoxForExt(model => model.Description)
                <p class="help-block">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: -15px">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div style="float: left">
                    <button type="submit" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary" title="Click to Update">Update</button>
                </div>
                <div style="float: right">
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Cancel", "Test", "Home", new { Model.Id, form = false }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "TestBody" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", title = "Click to Cancel" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
@Scripts.Render("~/scriptBundle/_test")
```

**_test.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#TestForm").formValidation({
        framework: "bootstrap",
        fields: {
            'Description': {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        callback: function(value) {
                            debugger;
                            var id = parseInt($("#Id").val(), 0) || 0;

                            if (value === "" && id === 0) {
                                return {
                                    valid: false,
                                    message: "Please enter a Description"
                                };
                            }

                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**_Test.cshtml**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Test
<table class="table table-bordered no-margin-bottom">
    <tr>
        <td>@Model.Id</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Model.Description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">@Ajax.ActionLink("Edit Test", "Test", "Home", new { id = Model.Id, form = true }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "TestBody" }, new { title = "Click to Edit Test" })</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little more research, great deal of trial and error, it came down to a minor addition of code to prevent the second form post. Please see my revised `_test.js` below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#TestForm").formValidation({
        framework: "bootstrap",
        fields: {
            'Description': {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        callback: function(value) {
                            debugger;
                            var id = parseInt($("#Id").val(), 0) || 0;

                            if (value === "" && id === 0) {
                                return {
                                    valid: false,
                                    message: "Please enter a Description"
                                };
                            }

                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}).on("success.form.fv", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    return false;
});
```